# React Redux Toolkits 1) Создать postsSlice 2) Получить массив постов на страницу feedPage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Мой код Sice:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState: [{
    id: "1",
    username: "Berik",
    title: "Rect",
    userimage: "Berik"
  }],
  reducers: {
  },
});

export default postSlice.reducer;

Страницу создал. Как получить массив постов на страницу feedPage?
```

Answer (score 0):

При условии что у вас есть готовый store с этим reducer'ом, к примеру названным posts.

const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)